# Should I use the same folder for .htaccess and .htpasswd?

Tags: .htaccess, wamp, .htpasswd

When I choose the same directory for .htaccess and .htpasswd, everything working fine.

But the situation below makes me sad.

I have one .htacces file in the root folder (johan) containing the code below.

```
AuthName "johan User"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile C:/wamp/www/johan/protectthisdir/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

.htpasswd is located at protectthisdir.
When I try to access the johan suddenly getting authentication required message box. But I need it only at protectthisdir. How to do this? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You should put the `.htaccess` file in the folder you want to protect, and not the root folder in your case.

The `.htpasswd` file should not be accessible from a browser so putting it above the DocumentRoot folder is a good idea. So in C:\wamp in your case.

PS:
It would be better to create a Virtual Host for your site to run in, in a completely different folder structure from the default wamp folders [See this post for help on that](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,124482)

Comment: Hello @RiggsFolly. Thanks for the reply. It was a new information for me that how to create virtual host in wamp. But now I haven't the administration privilege to edit the host file. Have a good day :)

Comment: You can copy the hosts file to your desktop, edit it there and then copy it back. Otherwise launch your editor using the `Run as Administrator` menu option.